# highlightedTextColor in case of editing in UITableView

Tags: uiview, uitableview, highlighting

I've a `UITableView` with custom cell, which contains some labels with `highlightedTextColor`:

`myLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

This works fine until I decided to make my table editable using:

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem`

When I click the "edit" button and click on a cell, I found the `highlightedTextColor` property doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the cell is being selected at all?  Try setting `allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES` on the `UITableView`.

Also, did you mean to use `[UIColor whiteColor]`?

Comment: It doesn't work . BTW What you mean by `Are you sure the cell is being selected at all?`

Comment: Does the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method get called when you are expecting to see your `highlightedTextColor`?  Are you perhaps turning off selection with `tableView:canSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: I am putting NSLog at start of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and can see it in the console and I don't have `canSelectRowAtIndexPath`.